# I cannot see any data from my pagination query

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I have 3 records in a database and want to display data from each record on a separate page using previous next links.

This script does not give errors but it does not display any data either. connect.php connects to my database and declares variables for table names.

```
<?php
include "connect.php";
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
$rec_limit = 1;

$Link = mysqli_connect($Host, $User, $Password, $Database);
$Query = "SELECT count(emp_id) FROM $Table_4";
$result = mysql_query($Query);
$rec_count = $row[0];

if( isset($_GET{'page'} ) )
{
   $page = $_GET{'page'} + 1;
   $offset = $rec_limit * $page ;
}
else
{
   $page = 0;
   $offset = 0;
}
$left_rec = $rec_count - ($page * $rec_limit);

$Query = "SELECT emp_id, emp_name, emp_salary ".
       "FROM $Table_4".
       "LIMIT $offset, $rec_limit";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "EMP ID :{$row['emp_id']}  <br> ".
         "EMP NAME : {$row['emp_name']} <br> ".
         "EMP SALARY : {$row['emp_salary']} <br> ".
         "--------------------------------<br>";
} 

if( $page > 0 )
{
   $last = $page - 2;
   echo "<a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?page=$last\">Previous</a> |";
   echo "<a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?page=$page\">Next</a>";
}
else if( $page == 0 )
{
   echo "<a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?page=$page\">Next Record</a>";
}
else if( $left_rec < $rec_limit )
{
   $last = $page - 2;
   echo "<a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?page=$last\">Previous Record</a>";
}

?>
```

Comment: are you getting data from your query?  you have to debug this by placing stuff in "if" clause.  It's good to have some debugging tools but if you dont.. then you can test in a basic way by placing a "die;" where you expect your code to go.  If the page still loads then it's not getting to that point.

Comment: @hamobi $Query = "SELECT * FROM $Table_4";
outputs all the data from the tables. The problem is the count in the select query. I'm not sure how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't run the query with custom offset and limit, there is no $result except the one for on the top of your script for getting total rows.

EDIT: you use mysqli_connect and mysql_query. i never used mysqli but it seems to me that you shouldn't be able to establish the connection with mysqli_ function and then use mysql_ functions for the rest. i might be wrong, check it yourself.

EDIT 2: there are many errors in your example, it's easier to correct them, so compare my code with your to see why your didn't work:

```
<?php

include "connect.php";

error_reporting(E_ALL - E_NOTICE);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

$rec_limit = 1;

$Link = mysqli_connect($Host, $User, $Password, $Database);
$Query = "SELECT count(emp_id) FROM $Table_4";
$result = mysqli_query($Link, $Query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
$rec_count = $row[0];

if( isset($_GET{'page'} ) )
{
   $page = $_GET{'page'} + 1;
   $offset = $rec_limit * $page ;
}
else
{
   $page = 0;
   $offset = 0;
}
$left_rec = $rec_count - ($page * $rec_limit);

$Query = "SELECT emp_id, emp_name, emp_salary ".
       "FROM $Table_4 ".
       "LIMIT $offset, $rec_limit";

$result = mysqli_query($Link, $Query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "EMP ID :{$row['emp_id']}  <br> ".
         "EMP NAME : {$row['emp_name']} <br> ".
         "EMP SALARY : {$row['emp_salary']} <br> ".
         "--------------------------------<br>";
} 

if( $page > 0 )
{
   $last = $page - 2;
   echo "<a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?page=$last\">Previous</a> |";
   echo "<a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?page=$page\">Next</a>";
}
else if( $page == 0 )
{
   echo "<a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?page=$page\">Next Record</a>";
}
else if( $left_rec < $rec_limit )
{
   $last = $page - 2;
   echo "<a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?page=$last\">Previous Record</a>";
}

?>
```

Comment: I've mysqli connect with mysql queries many times, yes I know it's sloppy but I'm learning.

Comment: the first part of my answer is the crucial one :)

Comment: Thanks! This was it? $result = mysqli_query($Link, $Query);

The next record has no limit i.e. I can keep clicking next even though there are only 3 records. Do I have to create a condition for next page?

Comment: please compare line by line, there are several major fixes needed for the script to work. You already know the total number of rows, it's in $rec_count, and you know the current page, so you can make a condition to block printing of link to the nonexisting page.

Answer (score 0):

you don't execute the query. here:

```
$Query = "SELECT emp_id, emp_name, emp_salary ".
       "FROM $Table_4".
       "LIMIT $offset, $rec_limit";
$result = mysql_query($Query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
```

**mysql_* extension is deprecated, please don't use it anymore, go towards pdo or mysqli**

Comment: That doesn't show any data and the field names from the echo statement no longer display, previous I saw 

EMP ID
EMP NAME
EMP SALARY

But no data.

Comment: your script runs on the previous `$result` defined with your first query. If it's still not what you want, your second query may be at fault

Comment: Félix Gagnon-Grenier I removed the first query still no data.

Comment: I'll try a different tutorial.